# CURDATE() with laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

> I'm new to laravel and i am wanting to use multiple where clauses and use curdate().

This is an example :

```
$data = DB::table('toutcome')->where('date', '>=', curdate())->where('Status', '=', 'A')->count('AppID');

return view('home', compact('data'));
```

It's not working at all.

Comment: try please `andWhere()` for the second condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So along with the answers in the comments:

```
    public function index()
    {
        // First query with DB::raw() variant
        $data = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->where('date', '>=', DB::raw('curdate()'))
            ->where('Status', '=', 'A')
            ->count('AppID');

        // Second query with Carbon variant
        $data2 = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->where('date', '>=', Carbon::now())
            ->where('Status', '=', 'A')
            ->count('AppID');

        // Third query with '@Sunny' whereRaw variant
        $data3 = DB::table('toutcome')
            ->whereRaw('date >= curdate()')
            ->where('Status', '=', 'A')
            ->count('AppID');

        return view('home', compact('data','data2','data3'));
    }
```

I'm not a big fan of compact() personally so I would write:

```
return view('home', ['data'=>&$data,'data2'=>&$data2,'data3'=>&$data3])
```

although personally (if you want to read on taking it further) read up on ViewComposers:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers

Comment: In second query, didn't you have Carbon::today() in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Change 
`where('date', '>=', curdate())`
to
`whereRaw('date >= curdate()')`

Comment: Other possibilities: `where('date', '>=', Carbon::now())` and `where('date', '>=', DB::raw('curdate()'))`

Comment: Thanks, this taught me a thing too! :)

Comment: @SunnyRGupta , thank you and Thanks Justion, can you look at the updated question please.